# adding a method to built-in class in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a method to the Array class in a rails app.  Where should I put this method?

EDIT to be clearer, obviously I put it in a file somewhere, but how do I tell the rails app about where to find it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a file at `lib/rails_extensions.rb`. Then, add your extensions like so:

```
class Array
  def bring_me_food
    # ...
  end

  def make_tea
    # ...
  end
end

class Hash
  def rub_my_shoulders
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then in `config/environment.rb`, add this:

```
require 'rails_extensions'
```

Your mileage with subservient objects may vary.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks.  I found, however, that this only works when I put the require line at the bottom of config/environment.rb

Comment: You're lucky to have such servient Hash's and Array's in your environment.

Comment: It's also worth to note that you may add your extensions in `config/initializers/rails_extensions.rb`. In that way, you don't have to add `require` in `environment.rb`. Tested in ruby 2.6.4 and rails 6.

Answer (score 6):

By default, when you call "require", Rails will look in (from the Rails edge source):

app
app/metal
app/models
app/controllers
app/helpers
app/services
lib
vendor

For simplicity's sake, put the file in lib/, and require it by name in your config/environment.rb, or you can put it in config/initializers/array_extension.rb, and it'll be automatically loaded.

Where I work, we've put all of our extensions to the core Ruby library into a plugin, and stored it in (Rails.root/)vendor/plugins/utilities/lib/core_ext, and then we require the individual extensions in the plugin's init.rb.

Another way to skin this cat: if you say, want to store your core extensions in Rails.root/core_ext, then you can add that path as a load path in your configuration block in environment.rb:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.load_paths << 'core_ext'
end
```

Then you can call "require 'array_extension'" from anywhere, and it'll load.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a new file, e.g. `array_extended.rb`

```
class Array

  def my_new_method()
    ...
  end

end
```

After that you may include this file with `require "array_extended.rb"`.
Be sure you don't override already existing methods as this may break other functionality.

Comment: But where do you put require "array_extended.rb" ?  That was my question really.